# Eve: Endpoint representing currently logged-in user

Tags: python, eve

I am using the auth feature in combination with oauth. I would like to have an endpoint like: `/api/v1/user/current` representing the currently logged-in user. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular Flask routing to achieve that. Remember Eve is a Flask subclass, so whatever works with Flask generally work with Eve too, enabling custom endpoints included:

```
from eve import Eve

app = Eve()

@app.route('/user/current')
def current_user():
    # perform your magic here
    user_name = your_own_logic()
    return 'Welcome back, %s' % user_name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

See [this article](http://nicolaiarocci.com/building-custom-endpoint-handlers-with-eve/) for details.

Comment: Yes that cool, but I'd like to have access to all the nice rest methods from eve without re-implement them.

Comment: You generally have access to eve methods there. Just import what you need and use at will. In the linked article (towards the bottom) I am importing `requires_auth` from eve, for example.